# SQL query question

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is the table "Answers".  I need to get count of QuestionNo that are "R", "W", "" for each section for given AcademicYear and TestNo.  What is the best SQL query?

```
AcademicYear  StudentID  TestNo Section QuestionNo  Answer

2010-2011        1        1        2        1        R
2010-2011        1        1        2        2        W
2010-2011        1        1        2        3        R
2010-2011        1        1        2        4         
2010-2011        1        1        2        5         
2010-2011        1        1        2        6         
2010-2011        1        1        2        7         
2010-2011        1        1        2        8         
2010-2011        1        1        2        9         
2010-2011        1        1        2        10
```

The end result should look like this:

```
Section QuestionNo  Answer   Count
   2         1         R       15
   2         1         W       25
   2         1                 100
   2         2         R       10
   2         2         W       50
   2         2                 10
   etc..
```

Sorry for not framming the question right for the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

I added some columns to the output to be more consistent with your question.

Just replace the ???  with the values you want.

```
SELECT section, question, answer, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table 
WHERE academicYear = ??? AND testNo = ???
GROUP BY section, question, answer
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
academicyear, testno,

 sum(case when answer='R' then 1 else 0 end) as Right,
 sum(case when answer='W' then 1 else 0 end) as Wrong
from 
T
group by academicyear, testno
```

Comment: also add a case for '' or is null